# Another Cash Register Program

Tags: java

I want to write a program that takes in the price, entered by the user, how much they pay and what their change is. I also want the program to specify the coins and notes due for their change.

I think I am pretty close, however when I run the program I just get 0 for the amount of coins and notes due.

I'm not looking for someone to write the program for me, I just need to know what I'm doing wrong, no doubt it is something simple that I overlooked but I can't figure it out.

This is what I've done so far, I know it's not very pretty but I'll work on that as I get more experienced.

Thanks.

```
Scanner cashregister = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Thank you for your purchase!");


    int amountDue = 0, amountPaid = 0, changeDue = 0;


    int fiftyEuro = 5000;

    int twentyEuro = 2000;

    int tenner = 1000;

    int fiver = 500;

    int two = 200;

    int one = 100;

    int fiftyCent = 50;

    int twentyCent = 20;

    int tenCent = 10;

    int fiveCent = 5;

    int twoCent = 2;

    int oneCent = 1;



    fiftyEuro = changeDue / 5000;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 5000;


    twentyEuro = changeDue / 2000;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 2000;


    tenner = changeDue / 1000;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 1000;


    fiver = changeDue / 500;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 500;


    two = changeDue / 200;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 200;


    one = changeDue / 100;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 100;


    fiftyCent = changeDue / 50;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 50;


    twentyCent = changeDue / 20;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 20;


    tenCent = changeDue / 10;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 10;


    fiveCent = changeDue / 5;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 5;


    twoCent = changeDue / 2;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 2;


    oneCent = changeDue / 1;

    changeDue = changeDue %= 1;


    if (amountDue > amountPaid)

        System.out.println("\nThe amount due must be less then or equal to the amount you are paying");


    System.out.println("\nThe amount due, in cents: ");

    amountDue = cashregister.nextInt();


    System.out.println("\nThe amount paid, in cents: ");

    amountPaid = cashregister.nextInt();

    changeDue = amountPaid - amountDue;


    System.out.println("\nYour change, in cents is: " + changeDue);


    System.out.println("\nThe change for " + changeDue + " is: ");


    System.out.println(fiftyEuro + "   \u20ac" + "50"); //€50 notes due

    System.out.println(twentyEuro + "   \u20ac" + "20"); //€20 notes due

    System.out.println(tenner + "   \u20ac" + "10"); //€10 notes due

    System.out.println(fiver + "   \u20ac" + "5"); //€5 notes due

    System.out.println(two + "   \u20ac" + "2"); //€2 coins due

    System.out.println(one + "   \u20ac" + "1"); //€1 coins due

    System.out.println(fiftyCent + "   50" + "c"); //50c coins due

    System.out.println(twentyCent + "   20" + "c"); //20c coins due

    System.out.println(tenCent + "   10" + "c"); //10c coins due

    System.out.println(fiveCent + "   5" + "c"); //5c coins due

    System.out.println(twoCent + "   2" + "c"); //2c coins due

    System.out.println(oneCent + "   1" + "c"); //1c coins due


    cashregister.close();

    return;

}
```

}

Here is an example of my output

Thank you for your purchase!

The amount due, in cents: 
2450

The amount paid, in cents: 
5000

Your change, in cents is: 2550

The change for 2550 is: 
0   €50
0   €20
0   €10
0   €5
0   €2
0   €1
0   50c
0   20c
0   10c
0   5c
0   2c
0   1c

As you can see it doesn't say how much of each note / coin the customer should get.

Comment: You should put your `scanner.nextInt()` above all your calculations..

Comment: You calculate `changeDue` _after_ all the other calculations that use `changeDue`. You need to rearrange the order of things.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, I'll make the necessary changes.

Comment: Please try to reduce the number of lines in the method.. writing too much of code inside one method is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move these codes after

```
    fiftyEuro = changeDue / 5000;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 5000;
    twentyEuro = changeDue / 2000;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 2000;
    tenner = changeDue / 1000;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 1000;
    fiver = changeDue / 500;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 500;
    two = changeDue / 200;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 200;
    one = changeDue / 100;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 100;
    fiftyCent = changeDue / 50;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 50;
    twentyCent = changeDue / 20;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 20;
    tenCent = changeDue / 10;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 10;
    fiveCent = changeDue / 5;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 5;
    twoCent = changeDue / 2;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 2;
    oneCent = changeDue / 1;
    changeDue = changeDue %= 1;
```

after these line..

```
    System.out.println("\nThe amount paid, in cents: ");
    amountPaid = cashregister.nextInt();
    changeDue = amountPaid - amountDue;
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something silly that I had done, it's nice to get someone else to look at it, sometimes it's hard to proof-read your own work :)